# Compare two table and make a combined table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can Anyone Please help me in this?
Thanks in Advance..

What I need is to compare the table 'Old' with 'New' and Make the column 'person' and Product ID' by formula in Result Table. (by combing 'Old' and 'New' Table).

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmrMV.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the data in table format instead of image? Edit post and copy data from excel to text and then mark the text and set it to code please.

Comment: You can treat tables in excel as database tables and do sql joins on fields with them. Each table needs to be in it's own sheet, with field names in row 1. Then the easiest way to do it is to link to them in a blank access database and use the query generator

Answer (score 1):

One way to to it is to copy all data from old table and new table to result and then remove duplicates (the built in Excel-feature). Would that do the trick or does it need to be code?

[image]

Comment: I accept that the mentioned remove duplicates method is the best simple way to do this. But I excepting to do this by formula and to record them as macro for later use. Can you help me in This?